# fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, api, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps

i'm making this web app using api from https://www.football-data.org

when i make the boilerplate for the web i get this error in my console

[image: error image]

```
const ENPOINT_JER = `${BASE_URL}competition/2002/standings`;
const ENPOINT_BEL = `${BASE_URL}competition/2003/standings`;
const ENPOINT_ING = `${BASE_URL}competition/2021/standings`;
const ENPOINT_SPA = `${BASE_URL}competition/2014/standings`;
const ENPOINT_PER = `${BASE_URL}competition/2015/standings`;

const fetchAPI = (url) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth-Token": API_KEY,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        console.log(`Error: ${res.status}`);
        return Promise.reject(new Error(res.statusText));
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve(res);
      }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

function getStandingJer() {
  if ("caches" in window) {
    caches.match(ENPOINT_JER).then(function (response) {
      if (response) {
        response.json().then(function (data) {
          console.log("Competition Data: " + data);
          showStanding(data);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  fetchAPI(ENPOINT_JER)
    .then((data) => {
      showStanding(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

i've already make the API_KEY variable

Comment: Is the server yours? probably not - you'll need to make the request from your server as that API probably doesn't allow CORS requests (i.e. requests from browsers)

Comment: by the way, you don't need to `return Promise.resolve/reject` in a `.then` ... just return, or throw an error

Comment: and since your `catch` does a `console.log(err);` the result from `fetchAPI` will ALWAYS be a resolved Promise - which is why your code is trying to read property `standings` of `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are browser plugins for suppressing cors while your app is in development:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

If you're using node and express there's a cors middleware package to help, but set up can still be tricky.
First import the module from the commandline with `npm install cors`;

```
then in your server.js file:
const   express =   require('express')
const   app =   express();
```

and then add cors() as an arg to the endpoint, before the callback.
More info in this guy's [book](https://flaviocopes.com/page/express-handbook/)